# PHP/MySQL Function Causes Others to Stop Working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 PHP files: an index.php, a config.php w/ MySQL database definitions and a functions.php file with three separate functions. When only one of the functions is called in the index file, things work fine. When I add just one of the other two, however, things stop working.

Using the following example/files, I get this error message where the second function falls in the index.php code: 
**Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in...line 37**, which corresponds to the DB query in that second function-- the get_chapter_dollars function.

I'm sure it's something simple, but what am I missing, here? Why is that second function causing problems?

**CONFIG.PHP**

```
<?php
define("BASE_URL","/dayofgiving/");
define("ROOT_PATH",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/dayofgiving/");

// Set variables for the database.

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "cdwyer_dspdog");
define("DB_PORT", "1234");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "pass");
```

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/dayofgiving/inc/config.php");

function get_state_stats() {
    require_once(ROOT_PATH . "inc/db.php");
    try {
        $results = $db->query("
        SELECT abb, fullname, dollars, alumnidollars, ugdollars, donors, alumnidonors, ugdonors
        FROM dog_states");
        $maxDollars = $db->query("
        SELECT MAX(dollars) 
        FROM dog_states;
        ");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data coudn’t be found.";
        exit;
    }

    $maxDollars = intval($maxDollars->fetchColumn(0));

    $stateInfo=array();

    while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // Will return boolean(false) when condition is no longer met.
        $stateAbb = $row["abb"];
        $thisDollars = $row["dollars"];
        $stateInfo[$stateAbb] = $row; // Loops through all states/rows one at a time, and adds all properties to the stateInfo variable w/ abbreviation as key.
        $stateInfo[$stateAbb]["opacity"] = ((($thisDollars / $maxDollars)*.5)+.5);
    }

    return $stateInfo;
}

function get_chapter_dollars() {
    require_once(ROOT_PATH . "inc/db.php");
    try {
        $dollarResults = $db->query("
        SELECT abb, fullname, dollars
        FROM dog_chapters
        ORDER BY dollars DESC
        LIMIT 5");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data coudn’t be found.";
        exit;
    }

    $chapterDollars=array();

    while ($row = $dollarResults->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // Will return boolean(false) when condition is no longer met.
        $chapterDollars[] = $row; // Loops through all (ie, top 5) chapters/rows one at a time, and adds all properties to the chapterDollars variable w/ number as key.
    }

    return $chapterDollars;
}

function get_chapter_donors() {
    require_once(ROOT_PATH . "inc/db.php");
    try {
        $donorResults = $db->query("
        SELECT abb, fullname, donors
        FROM dog_chapters
        ORDER BY donors DESC
        LIMIT 5");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data coudn’t be found.";
        exit;
    }

    $chapterDonors=array();

    while ($row = $donorResults->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // Will return boolean(false) when condition is no longer met.
        $chapterDonors[] = $row; // Loops through all (ie, top 5) chapters/rows one at a time, and adds all properties to the chapterDollars variable w/ number as key.
    }

    return $chapterDonors;
}

?>
```

**INDEX.PHP (portion)**

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/dayofgiving/inc/config.php"); ?>
    <?php require_once(ROOT_PATH . "db/functions.php"); ?>
<?php $tempStateStats = get_state_stats() ?>
var jsonStates = <?php echo json_encode($tempStateStats); ?>;
<?php $returnChapterDollars = get_chapter_dollars() ?>
<?php echo $returnChapterDollars[0]["abb"];?>
```

Comment: You need to illustrate where `$db` comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues with require_once working correctly with my version of PHP (5.3.3). For the purpose of testing try changing it to require or include for each instance on the page and see if it works.

Comment: Nailed it. I had wondered about that at one point, then forgot to test. Specifically, the 'require_once's in the functions file needed to be replaced w/ 'require'...in case anyone else runs into this issue. It was the second function where the error was occuring, so I assume the r_o on the db.php file was failing or something. Thanks again!